# How to select a check box in a dialog box that pops open when mounting a drive?

Tags: dialog, applescript

I'm trying to launch a dialog box with a checkbox already selected, but no amount of research is showing me how to do this. Included is my script that brings up the dialog box:

```
    mount volume "smb://xyz-server/user-share/servervolume"
    mount volume "smb://xyz-server/useradmin-share/servervolume"
```

[image: mount dialog]

Comment: Not a solution, but the `Finder` tell block is not needed at all. `mount volume` belongs to `Standard Additions`

Answer (score 0):

There is no checkbox dialog in Applescript's Standard dialogs. You can use a Choose from List here, perhaps? Something like:

```
property serverList : {"smb://xyz-server/user-share/servervolume", "smb://xyz-server/useradmin-share/servervolume"}
set serverChoice to (choose from list serverList with prompt "Please select the volume(s) to mount" default items (item 1 of serverList) OK button name {"Mount"} cancel button name {"Cancel"} with multiple selections allowed)
repeat with thisPath in serverChoice
    tell application "Finder"
        mount volume thisPath
    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: Hmm no that didn't quite work, it brought up the two servers then after I clicked them it brought me to the same screen without the checkbox checked. [link] (http://imgur.com/U9zM993) this link should lead to a picture of what I mean.

Comment: ok, you should have posted the pic in your original question, to better explain what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Yea sorry, but there is no checkbox featured in simple AppleScript dialog boxes, etc, but you could use a dialog box with custom buttons eg.

```
set isOver13 to the button returned of (display dialog "Are you 13 or older?" buttons {"Cancel", "No", "Yes"})

(returns "Yes" or "No" for the button selected)
```

or like "jweaks" said, you could also use something like choose from list, eg.

```
set isOver13 to item 1 of (choose from list {"Yes", "No"})

(returns "Yes" or "No" for the item choosen)
```

but if you desperatly want to use a checkbox then, there is 1 other way :-o

you will need to cross over to cocoa-applescript (ASObjC), this is basicly the next step in applescript coding, ASObjC is pretty much Objective-C actions, commands etc... but in AppleScript coding language :o. To do this, you need to get Xcode, and look up AppleScript Objective-C tutorials ;)

```
Hope this Helped :D
```

Comment: I'm not trying to create my own separate dialog box but rather edit one that auto launches to get the check box to default to being activated for instance in this image [link] (imgur.com/U9zM993)

Answer (score 0):

The window belongs to the process `NetAuthAgent`, you can click the checkbox only with GUI scripting.

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat until exists window 1 of process "NetAuthAgent"
        delay 0.2
    end repeat
    tell process "NetAuthAgent"
        click checkbox 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: So how would I implement the mounting drives into the script? I tried something like

Comment: mount volume "smb://xyz-server/user-share/servervolume"
mount volume "smb://xyz-server/useradmin-share/servervolume"
tell application "System Events"
 repeat until exists window 1 of process "NetAuthAgent"
  delay 0.2
 end repeat
 tell process "NetAuthAgent"
  click checkbox 1 of window 1
 end tell
end tell

Comment: Well that didnt work, basically I put the mount drives code before the script you gave me in script editor and it didn't work. So I was wondering if there was a certain place for them?

Comment: GUI scripting works in real-time, so you have to mount one volume after another and run the snippet twice. You might also close the window programmatically